# Write a query for overlapping time in this example

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

Imagine that i have a table with below data:
[image]

I want to write a query that give:
customers that have overlapping time for example :

```
Row 2,3
because customer of these are the same and the overlapping time
```

Comment: what kind of output you want ??

Comment: Does not matter, Table

Comment: what are you using mysql or sql server? and which version? while answer by wewesthemenace is correct based on the limited information you have provided, there may be better alternatives based on your rdbms and version

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `SELF-JOIN`. This may not be efficient for large tables:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM TestData t1
INNER JOIN TestData t2
    ON t2.Customer = t1.Customer
    AND t2.EndDate >= t1.StartDate
    AND t2.StartDate <= t1.EndDate
    AND t1.Row <> t2.Row
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c818e/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.Row
      ,a.customer
      ,a.start
       ,a.end
      ,b.ColumnId AS OverlappedId 
      ,b.InTime   AS OverlappedInTime 
      ,b.OutTime  AS OverlappedOutTime 
  FROM Time  AS a 
  JOIN Time  AS b ON ((a.start BETWEEN b.start AND b.end) 
                       OR  (a.end BETWEEN b.start AND b.end)) 
                      AND  (a.row!= b.row)
```